# Create a simple JS object that modifies itself

Tags: javascript, oop

So I get very turned around with object-oriented JavaScript.  What I want is to create a simple global object (like jQuery, _, d3, etc.) that you can call as a function with a single argument.  It then checks to see whether it already knows that argument, and if it does, returns the cached info. Otherwise it gets the new info and caches it before returning it.  So, the equivalent of:

```
var cache = {};

function foo(arg) {
  if (!cache[arg]) cache[arg] = doSomething(arg);
  return cache[arg];
}

function doSomething(arg) {
    return arg+"!!!";
}


foo("hi"); //returns "hi!!!" after calling doSomething
foo("hi"); //returns "hi!!!" from cache without calling doSomething
```

I can't figure out how to roll up cache into foo itself, so that it checks/updates its own hash when called instead of just using a separate global variable.  I know it would work if I did something like this:

```
function cacher() {
  this.cache = {};
}

cacher.prototype = {
    update: function(arg) {
      if (!this.cache[arg]) this.cache[arg] = doSomething(this.cache[arg]);
      return this.cache[arg];
    }
}
```

But in that case I'd have to call `foo.update()` instead of just `foo()`. The latter is what I want.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

functions are objects, and often handy ones at that:

```
function foo(arg) {
  if (!foo["cache"+arg]) foo["cache"+arg] = doSomething(arg);
  return foo["cache"+arg];
}
```

Of course, this only works with unique string and number arguments; it confuses "1" with 1.
It also will not cache for returns of false, 0, "", etc.
If that matters to you, look into using [WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) for apps needing strong-type lookup capability.

Comment: lol; i'm just a victim of the downvote driveby, you say "why" they say "goodbye"...

Comment: Happens to the best and worst of us... :(

Comment: @dandavis The car was going at high speed apparently.

Answer (score 0):

How about a facade to your encapsulated caching class?

```
var foo = (function() {

    function cacher() {
        this.cache = {};
    }

    cacher.prototype.update = function(arg) {

        if (!this.cache[arg]) this.cache[arg] = this.doSomething(this.cache[arg]);

        return this.cache[arg];
    }

    cacher.prototype.doSomething = function(arg) {
        //Do something with arg and return
    }

    var func = new cacher();

    return function(arg) {
        return func.update(arg);
    }

}());

var val = foo("checking");
```

You can make your caching class as complex as you need it with a simple interface, in this case `foo` will be the return value of the private scope, a function, that takes a parameter and uses the caching class to generate values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's really what you are looking for but the static variable seem solve your problem like that:

```
    function foo(arg)
    {
      if (typeof foo.mycache == 'undefined')
        foo.mycache = {};
      if (typeof foo.mycache[arg] == 'undefined')
        foo.mycache[arg] = doSomething(arg);
      return (foo.mycache[arg]);
    }
    function doSomething(arg)
    {
      return arg+"!!!";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written a function some time ago, that converts a "regular" function to a function which acts as you describe. Use it like this: `var cachedFunction = memoize(regularFunction)`. The cache is kept inside a closure. Should work with an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
function memoize(oriFunc) {
  var cache = [];
  var notFound = {};

  function arrayEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
      return false;
    }
    var ri = arr1.length;
    while (ri--) {
      if (arr1[ri] !== arr2[ri]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  function cacheGet(newArgs) {
    var ri = cache.length;
    while (ri--) {
      var item = cache[ri];
      if (arrayEqual(item.args, newArgs)) {
        return item.result;
      }
    }

    // I'm returning a special object, since false, -1, or undefined could be
    // results of the call

    return notFound;
  }

  function cachePut(args, result) {
    cache.push({args: args, result: result});
    return result;
  }

  return function() {
    var cacheResult = cacheGet(arguments);
    if (cacheResult !== notFound) {
      return cacheResult;
    }
    var freshResult = oriFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    return cachePut(arguments, freshResult);
  };
}
```